# Button on click shows another button group?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to create button event which displays another group of buttons.
Here is my code so far:

If someone choose a button from 1 - 5 and press this button. This should trigger another group button.

```
 <div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p class="bg-danger">Step 1: Choose number</p>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">1</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">2</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">3</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">4</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">5</a>
    </div>
```

For example:
This group of buttons should appear if button 2 is pressed:

```
<p class="bg-danger">Step 2: Output</p>
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">11</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">22</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">33</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">44</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">55</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">66</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">77</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">88</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">99</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">110</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">220</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to add `id` or `class` to your elementsn then you can select them from jquery.

Comment: could you post some example?

Comment: Have your second group's `div` set to `visible = false`, and then have your first button set the visibility of that div to true when clicked. Look at the `onClick` and  `getElementsByClassName` documentation for details.

Comment: Hide the text using HTML5 and CSS3 then use Jquery show() method to take the click event effect. $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show();
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

Take a look at the example in **[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n0x5xssk/5/)**.

1. Adding `step-1` to the group of anchors (1 2 3 ....) so we can affect the click event to them using selector `$('.step-1 a')`.
2. Adding attribut `data-id` contain the `id` of group concerned by click.
3. Adding `step-2` to all divs containing groups of buttons so we can hide them all before showing the clicked one using `$('.step-2').hide();`.
4. Adding `ids` to all divs containing groups of buttons, then if we want to select a specific group button for the clicked button in `step-1`.

**JS :**

```
$('.step-1 a').click(function(){
    $('.step-2').hide(); //Hide others groups
    $('#'+$(this).data('id')).show(); //Show clicked group
});
```

**HTML :**

```
<div class="col-md-12" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <p class="bg-danger">Step 1: Choose number</p>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified step-1">
        <a href="#" data-id='group-1' class="btn btn-primary">1-2-3...</a>
        <a href="#" data-id='group-2' class="btn btn-primary">2</a>
        <a href="#" data-id='group-3' class="btn btn-primary">3</a>
        <a href="#" data-id='group-4' class="btn btn-primary">4</a>
        <a href="#" data-id='group-5' class="btn btn-primary">5</a>
    </div>
</div>


<div id="group-1"  class="col-md-12 step-2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;display:none">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">1</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">2</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">3</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">4</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">5</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">6</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">7</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">8</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">9</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">10</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="group-2" class="col-md-12 step-2" style="margin-bottom: 10px;display:none">
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">11</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">22</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">33</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">44</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">55</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">66</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">77</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">88</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">99</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">110</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">220</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Works perfect until I change the main group buttons name("step-1")
Any suggestions how to fix that?

Comment: You mean the class `step-1` ? if you change it in html you have to update js code also with new class.

Comment: in step-1 we have 5 buttons each of them has a name from 1-5.
When I change 1 to (for example 1-2-3). It's not working anymore.

Comment: Yes that will not work you can add an `data` with `id`... i'll update my answer right now.